# Topshelf throwing error while installing Windows service

Tags: .net, windows, topshelf

When I am trying to install a windows service getting error as below.
I have verified that the user account has permission to Log on as a service.
Also I am running the installation by logging in as the same user.
Running command

```
'C:\HostedApps2\Apps\ExceptionDefinition\ABC.Cloud.AMAM.ExDefinition.Api.exe install -e "Development" -u "eeur1@ABC.com" -p "GussMaPs"'
```

Exception is this

```
The transacted install has completed.
fail: Topshelf.HostFactory[0]
      The service terminated abnormally
System.InvalidOperationException: The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed. ---> System.Component
el.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.HostInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.TransactedInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.Install.TransactedInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedState)
   at Topshelf.StartParameters.SpWindowsHostEnvironment.InstallService(InstallHostSettings settings, Action`1 beforeI
all, Action afterInstall, Action beforeRollback, Action afterRollback)
   at Topshelf.Hosts.InstallHost.Run()
   at Topshelf.HostFactory.Run(Action`1 configureCallback)
------- End Executable Output -------
```

> Things I have verified:
>   1. The user account has permission to log on as a service.
>   2. Used perfmon tool to identify the error but there is no result with Access denied.

**The suspect we have is that the user name we are using to install the service belongs to a different domain than that of the PC where we are trying to install the service.**

Comment: Are you running the installation by running from an *elevated* command prompt? You need *administrative* permissions to install a service, not the "log on as a service" right (that only comes in later, when the service actually has to start).

Comment: Yes. Running via elevated command prompt, cmd as run as administrator.

Comment: "Access is denied"

Comment: Any solutions from anyone please.